# What is the correct way to store an array / tuple of id's in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays

I am redesigning a local IP management site, and need some help. Currently, there is a foreign key building ID associated with a certain subnet ID, so that the client knows which building the subnet is in. However, a problem that has risen is that a subnet may be split across multiple buildings. Now that the subnet-to-building paradigm no longer holds, I am at a loss for the correct way to manage this.

One option that comes immediately to mind and just seems bad is to change the building id field to a string of comma-separated building ID's. It's quick and it works, but it gives me a bad feeling.

Another idea that has come to mind is creating a BuildingIDTuple table, where multiple rows may exist mapping a subnet id to a buildingid.

```
subnet id | building id
------------------------
    1     |      2 
    1     |      3
```

This method seems cleaner and more future-proof, but I can also imagine the sql queries causing many headaches.

The ideal method I would think is to have an array of building ID's in the subnet table, but I don't think those exist.

So, what would be the best way to design what I am doing? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create the extra table, the required join will never be that complicated.

Parsing a comma-separated list or whatever will be what gives you a headache.

Comment: That's what I figured, but you guys have removed all doubt. Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

never store a set of values in a single database column!! break them out into a new table, each value as an individual row!!  Otherwise you will be a slave to splitting those CSV values out each time you query them.  Your `BuildingIDTuple` table is the way to go.  The queries are not harder, but you will need to support possible multiple rows comming back for each subnet.